# Proper way to chain 2 async tasks in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, chaining

I have two async tasks, namely task 1 and task 2.

I need to run task 1 first and then task 2 just after but I do not want to couple the two by calling task 2 in the onPostExecute implementation of task 1; because I use task 1 as stand alone in other circumstances.

I there a way to have the two async tasks defined without being bounded to each other and chain them in specific circumstances?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you do a simple if-else in onPostExecute of task 1, to start/not the task 2?

Comment: in the onPostExecute of the first you could trigger an event (intent, method, handler, ...) that start the second

Comment: @Cԃաԃ This might be a possible solution but I am trying to see if there is a neater way to achieve this

Comment: @Yume117 - I am trying not to call task 2 directly from the onPostExecute of task 1.

Comment: Then use a service that manage de tasks and with a broadcast receiver you get the events

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
final Executor directExecutor = new Executor() {
  public void execute(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
  }
};
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
  task1.executeOnExecutor(directExecutor, params1);
  task2.executeOnExecutor(directExecutor, params2);
});
```

I don't have android SDK on my machine now, so I can't verify it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
YourAsyncClass1 thread1 = new YourAsyncClass1();
thread1.execute(inputArgument1);

    try {
        outputResult1 = thread1.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
if(outputResult1 == true /*Or expected result*/){
  YourAsyncClass2 thread2 = new YourAsyncClass2();
  thread2.execute(inputArgument2);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But if task 1 takes 10 minutes to complete, wont the try catch be executed only once before the 10 minutes mark and hence missing when task 1 actually completes?

Comment: Hi, The thing is, thet with this you call `thread1.get()` and that part is responsible for the waiting. The `try{} catch{}` block is indeed going to be executed only once, but the waiting (the whole 10 minutes) is executed on the first pass by the block and in the part I mentioned.

Comment: I will try this approach asap. But when looking at this solution, if I run the thread1.get() on the UI thread, it will freeze the UI thread for the whole 10 minutes right? Therefore I guess I should call the .get() in another Async task. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you execute `.get()` on the main thread (activity) it will freeze it - yes. I thought that's the main goal, but apparently it's not, so please clarify the life cycle of each of the two `AsyncTasks`. What I mean is to describe a test scenario so that we can see when is the task1 executed, when and where do you expect it's result (the same for task2). It's not obligatory to call `.get()`, but you can also set a flag on the `onPostExecute()` to see if the task has finished if you don't want to wait for it.